# Setting proxy for IIS account for ABCPDF

Tags: iis, abcpdf, abcpdf9

I'm currently using ABCPDF to transform HTML into PDF. We have a proxy and since ABCPDF internally calls MSIE under the AppPools user account, NetworkService in my case, the proxy has not been set.

I have tried to use Microsofts BITSAdmin tool to set the proxy for NetworkService (**bitsadmin /util /setieproxy NetworkService MANUAL_PROXY PROXY_NAME null**) However its still timing out.

Anyone have any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: Can you run the app pool under a user account instead of NetworkService?

Comment: Unfortunately we cant :(

Answer (score 0):

With AbcPdf 8+ Its much easier to just change the render engine to Geko and then it dosn't need MSIE and the output seams to much more accurate.

```
var theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately we have switched to a different method of rendering HTML -> PDFs so I am unable to test this how the proxy will react to this :(